# No se visualiza imagen HTML en correo

Tags: html, python, email, base64, img

Que tal espero puedan apoyarme, estoy creando un generador de codigos QR y lo que haces es anexar el codigo como imagen HTLM al correo y enviarlo, el codigo funciona, el problema es que cuando llega el correo no se visualiza ninguna imagen, aparece en blanco. Les dejo el fragmento de creacion y anexo, estas son las librerias que estoy usando

```
 import qrcode
 from io import BytesIO
 from PIL import Image
 import base64

# Crear el código QR
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=1, box_size=8, border=4)
    qr.add_data(df.iloc[i])
    qr.make(fit=True)
    img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
    
    # Convertir la imagen del código QR en una cadena de bytes
    buffered = BytesIO()
    img.save(buffered, format="PNG")
    img_str = base64.b64encode(buffered.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")
    
    # Crear el contenido HTML para el correo electrónico con el código QR
    html_content = f"<html><body><h1>Este es un mensaje de prueba con el código QR adjunto:</h1><br><img src='data:image/png;base64,{img_str}'/></body></html>"
```

Comment: coloca un salto de línea justo antes del `src=` y otro antes del `/>` del img, puede que estés encontrando un límite [de largo de línea](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-2.1.1) ( 78 ). verifica siempre el source del email en el cliente de correo. por lo general vas a ver que las líneas llegan al caracter 76 + CR + LF y si el salto cae justo en el tag se genera un html inválido

Comment: Muchas Gracias, ya lo realice pero sin exito
Estoy usando la API de sendinblue para el envio de los correos y curioso en sendinblue al momento de abrir el registro de envios y visualiza el correo ahi si aparece el codigo QR pero en los correos recibidos, nada todo blanco

Comment: dada la variedad de clientes de correo ( y los diferentes tipos de relays entre medio ) lo mas aconsejable es enviar un mail y al recibirlo verificar el source "ver original" suele estar como opción. no está de mas agregar en el `alt` el texto codificado en el QR y el alto/ancho esperado. de esa manera si algun paso intermedio está removiendo o reemplazando la imagen podes detectarlo facilmente